# Basketball Tournament Simulation: array is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am setting up a basketball torunament that should run from start to bottom with a push of a button. But error console says my Teamarray is not defined. What is wrong with my code?

```
   function teamArray(list)
//Assumes: all basketball teams
//Returns: a random team from the list
{
var teamArray, randomIndex;

teamArray = ['Sales', 'HR', 'Accounting', 'Marketing', 'Engineering', 'Manufacturing', 'IT', 'Legal'];

randomIndex = RandomInt(0, list.length-1);

index=0;
while (index < teamArray.length) {
teamArray[index] = randomIndex;
index = index * 1;
}

return teamArray;

document.getElementById('team1').value = teamArray[0];
document.getElementById('team2').value = teamArray[1];
document.getElementById('team3').value = teamArray[2];
document.getElementById('team4').value = teamArray[3];
document.getElementById('team5').value = teamArray[4];
document.getElementById('team6').value = teamArray[5];
document.getElementById('team7').value = teamArray[6];
document.getElementById('team8').value = teamArray[7];

}
```

EDIT:

```
<input type="button" value="Start Tournament" onclick="teamArray(list); AddBonus(); TotalScore(); Winner(); ">
```

Comment: Where does it say the error is occurring?

Comment: You are returning teamArray from the function and then doing some changes in the dom after that!Secondly, are you sure you are using the correct spelling (dont wanna sound condescending but it has happened to me several times)

Comment: Please show the code for your button. If your console says "Teamarray" with a capital "T" and lowercase "a" as in your question then that's your first problem: JavaScript is case sensitive and your function is "teamArray" not "Teamarray". Beyond that there are numerous issues with the function, including (but not limited to) the ones RobG detailed below.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Start Tournament" onclick="teamArray(list); AddBonus(); TotalScore(); Winner(); ">

Comment: my onclick is right, it is just that it keeps saying my teamArray function is not defined

Comment: Where is `RandomInt()` defined? If there is other, invalid code in the same script block as your `function teamArray()` then `teamArray()` may not have been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> randomIndex = RandomInt(0, list.length-1);
```

What does `RandomeInt` return? Is it a random number between 0 and list.length-1 inclusive?

```
> index=0;
```

The identifier `index` is not declared so at this point it becomes a global variable.

```
> while (index < teamArray.length) { 
>      teamArray[index] = randomIndex; 
>      index = index * 1;
```

Multiplying a number by 1 just returns the number, this should produce an endless loop, perhaps you meant:

```
index += 1;
```

or

```
++index;
```

.

> } 
>   return teamArray;

No code after the return is executed. I’m not sure what you are trying to do, what are you expecting teamArray to be? An array of numbers? Of members from the original teamArray? You seem to be replacing the declared members with numbers.

Comment: Also that while loop (once the `* 1` is fixed) would replace every element in the array with the same random number.